# How permissions of a role be overridden with the permission of a user in membership class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am working in MVC3. I have created 3 roles: Administrator,Manager and Staff and have manager1 and manager2 in manager role. I want to give add,edit,view,delete privilege to manager. I don't want to give delete privilege to manager1. Can i override the  rights of user over roles?If yes please tell me how to do it using membership class?Any good articles on providing privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use the deny technique..

 public class DenyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            return !base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        }
    }

use this like authorizeattribute only.
```

Comment: that helped me.I would like to know more options it

Comment: It works fine for me. But when i use deny attribute before method it denies that action and is redirected to Logon page. I want a notification /alert message instead of it. Can u explain how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

first, membership providers doesn't provide any priveleges, they just stores account, profile, roles.
access to some actions you can give to roles and/or users, setting attibute `[AuthorizeAttribute(Roles = "role1", Users = "manager2")]` on controllers and actions. so using these technic you can extend priveleges for manager2.

Comment: [AuthorizeAttribute(Roles = "Manager", Users = "manager2")] will give privelege to manager2 only and it restricts from manager1 from acessing.So the above mentioned is equal to [AuthorizeAttribute( Users = "manager2")] only.

Comment: when [AuthorizeAttribute( Users = "manager2")] is used before a method it allows that action for manager2. It denies that action for manager1 and is redirected to Logon page. I want a notification /alert message instead of it. Can u explain how to do it?

Comment: main idea is to increase rights, not to reduce. so role role1 can read and user manager1 can also delete etc.